What is the absolute Value of Normal force on a block on Wedge?
So i have been solving problems of Newton's Laws of motion and this thing has been quite conflicting for me. I wont complicate my question. I just need one answer.
What is the absolute value of normal force on a block of mass M on a wedge?
I know it seems a pretty dull question but hear me out!
I am getting 2 different values of normal using 2 different ways.
1st Method :-

Here, I balance out forces in vertical direction by taking a component of N in vertical direction. So here the value comes out to be,
N = mg/cos(theta)
2nd method :-

[Theta is still theta i just couldn't find appropriate image to put up]
Here, I balance out forces by taking a component of mg in direction on N.
(Basically rotating the coordinate axis in which i am balancing forces)
So here, N comes out to be,
N = mg.cos(theta)
So, In both of my methods, The block is same, wedge is same and the scenario in which i am calculating Normal is also same! So Why? Why do we have 2 different values of N?
Shouldn't it be same no matter how we calculate it?
This question may be silly but please!! If you can, Satisfy my curiosity!

If you work in a horizontal and vertical coordinate system (your 1st method), then both components of the acceleration are non-zero. In other words, we have
$$F_{\text{net},y} = N\cos\theta - mg = ma_y$$
and since $a_y$ is not zero, it's not true that $N\cos\theta = mg$.
We can see that the vertical acceleration is non-zero from the fact that, after the we release the block from rest, its height goes down as it slides down the incline.
Now, it is possible to solve the problem in horizontal/vertical coordinates. We just need to incorporate the fact that the $x$ and $y$ components of the acceleration are related as the block moves along the incline. Specifically, we have the constraint
$$a_y = a_x \tan\theta$$
Our Newton's 2nd law equations are
\begin{align}
F_{\text{net},x} = -N \sin\theta &= ma_x\\
F_{\text{net},y} = N\cos\theta - mg &= ma_y
\end{align}
Plugging in the constraint, we get the system of equations
\begin{align}
m a_x &= - N \sin\theta\\
m a_x \tan\theta &= N\cos\theta - mg
\end{align}
and by eliminating $a_x$, we get an equation for $N$:
\begin{align}
&-N \sin\theta \tan\theta = N\cos\theta - mg\\
\rightarrow &N (\sin\theta \tan\theta + \cos\theta) = mg\\
\rightarrow &N \left(\frac{\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta}{\cos\theta}\right) = mg
\end{align}
Since $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$, this is just
\begin{align}
\frac{N}{\cos\theta} = mg\\ \rightarrow \boxed{N = mg \cos\theta}
\end{align}
That is, we recover the same result in this coordinate system as in the coordinate system of your 2nd method, but the constraint is much less straightforward to implement. This is the motivation for working in the parallel/perpendicular coordinates.

So it really was a pretty dull question

The first method doesn't work because the forces are not balanced in the vertical direction. A block on a ramp tends to accelerate downwards, so there should be a net vertical downwards force. The second method works because the block does not accelerate in the direction orthogonal to the ramp, so the forces are balanced in that direction.
